# C string output not performing as expected

Tags: c, getline

In C running in Visual Studio Express 2013 on a Windows 7 system, I have the following code which is intended to print out the lines in a text file on which a comment appears. Such lines are indicated in the input file by a # sign as the first character in a line. Assuming a line is:

```
#George Washington lives here
```

when I execute the program, it prints out:

```
comment: α°/
```

**Why isn't my code printing out the line?** It has no problem detecting these lines and otherwise processing them.

```
string str;
ifstream in;
in.open(filename); 
if (in.is_open()) 
   getline (in, str);
   while (in) {
   if (str[0] == '#') { printf("\ncomment: %s", str); }
```

Comment: I think your `if` block should be in brackets

Comment: This looks more like C++ than C.

Comment: Looks like your `getline` and `while` lines are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 you can configure the character set between Unicode and Multibyte. You can find it in the project propriety.

To "normalize" the string you can add c_str()

```
printf("\ncomment: %s", str.c_str());
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is likely an encoding mismatch. No, `c_str` [doesn't normalize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) stuff in any meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz and all. That did it! New to C++ (yes, you are correct @Klas-Lindbäck )  but learning fast. This will help me dig much deeper into the workings of strings, c-strings and all that good stuff. But for now, I'm getting output I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: ..sorry Lorenz. As a newbie, I can't yet vote up your answer.